# How to change this function to get the opendatasource server name dynamically

Tags: sql-server, function

I have the next function created, a simple union from two tables, one from the current server, and the other from a remote server:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_AllData] ()
RETURNS @tmp TABLE
    (
    Id      int,
    Name    varchar(100)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tmp
        SELECT Id, Name 
        FROM Table1

    INSERT INTO @tmp
        SELECT Id, Name 
        FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLOLEDB', 'Data Source=SERVER1;user id=xxx;password=yyy').Database1.dbo.Table1

    RETURN
END

--SELECT * FROM fn_AllData()
```

The function works fine in this way.

Now I need to obtain the server name dynamically, from another parameters table.

It should be easy like this:

```
DECLARE @SERVERNAME as varchar(20)

SELECT @SERVERNAME = Value 
FROM Parameters 
WHERE Name = 'SERVERNAME'
[...]

INSERT INTO @tmp
    SELECT Id, Name 
    FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLOLEDB', 'Data Source=' + @SERVERNAME + ';user id=xxx;password=yyy').Database1.dbo.Table1
```

But `Opendatasource` does not accept parameters.

Is there any way to achieve my goal keeping my code in a function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, i hope this works

```
DECLARE @SERVERNAME as NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @INSERTQUERY AS NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT @SERVERNAME=Value 
FROM Parameters WHERE Name='SERVERNAME'

[...]

SET @INSERTQUERY = 'INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT Id, Name FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''''SQLOLEDB'''', ''''Data Source=' + @SERVERNAME + ';user id=xxx;password=yyy'''').Database1.dbo.Table1'

EXEC (@INSERTQUERY)
```

Comment: This proposed idea is giving me syntax errors, when tries to concat the variable @tmp.

And the execution of sp_executesql from a function.

Need more ideas.

Comment: @Jortx, I edited the query, I assumed it's the data type has to be the same within each other, the variable tmp, servername, and insertquery, there I made them NVARCHAR, I don't know whether VARCHAR would be work for EXEC of not, I haven't tried, maybe you could try that? And I read some articles, it says only EXEC (StringCommand) also could work without using sp_executesql execution, please let us know how it goes, i hope it works

Comment: I have the same two problems with the new code. First one is not possible to concat '+@tmp+' with the varchar/nvarchar because @tmp is declared as TABLE type. Second one is not possible to use EXEC inside a function.